# Access context inside scope function

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to access context somehow inside scope function.

How can i do that?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    ....

    private val scanCallback = object: ScanCallback() {
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
            result?.let {
                Log.i("__BLEGATT", "Found Ble Device: ${it.device.name ?: "Unnamed"} " +
                        "addres: ${it.device.address}")
                if ( it.device.address == "Thermometer" ) {
                    if ( isScanning ) {
                        stopBleScan()
                    }
                    it.device.connectGatt(******MainActivity.this*********, false, gattCallback)
                }

            }
        }
    }

    .....
}
```

First parameter of `connectGatt` function needs `context`
As yon can see my code, i coudlnt write `MainActivity.this`.

Comment: This is Kotlin, change `MainActivity.this` with `this@MainActivity`

Comment: @Zain thnx working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get context like this in case of scope in kotlin:

```
 result?.let{
     it.device.connectGatt(this@MainActivity, false, gattCallback)
}
```